# WSO2 ESB: XSD validation on XML

Tags: xml, validation, xsd, wso2-esb

I am using WSO2 ESB and trying to create XML dynamically and apply some validation on XML.
But gets declaration in XML.
Please help me to correct below error.

Here is my sample code.

My Test API is

```
<resource methods="GET" uri-template="/{id}/transactions?page={page}&limit={limit}&startDate={startDate}&endDate={endDate}" faultSequence="ReturnError">
  <inSequence>
     <property name="uri.var.page" expression="$ctx:uri.var.page" scope="default" type="INTEGER"></property>
     <property name="uri.var.limit" expression="$ctx:uri.var.limit" scope="default" type="INTEGER"></property>

     <enrich>
        <source type="inline" clone="true">
           <jsonObject><id>1</id><page>1</goalId><limit>1</limit></jsonObject>
        </source>
        <target type="body" />
    </enrich>
    <validate>
        <schema key="MyXsd"></schema>
        <on-fail>
           <property name="clientErrorCode" value="2000"></property>
           <property name="clientErrorMessage" value="Invalid Param."></property>
           <property name="HTTP_SC" value="400" scope="axis2"></property>
           <sequence key="RetrunErrorWithMessage"></sequence>
        </on-fail>
     </validate>

   <inSequence>
</resource>
```

MyXsd is

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xs:element name="jsonObject">
     <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>

                    <xs:element type="xs:positiveInteger" name="id"></xs:element>
                    <xs:element type="xs:positiveInteger" name="page"></xs:element>
                    <xs:element type="xs:positiveInteger" name="limit"></xs:element>

        </xs:sequence>
     </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you. Replace any hard coded with your dynamic. I am assuming C# and .Net

```
    static class XPathValidation
{
    public static void validate(string assignmentXML)
    {
        try
        {
            XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
            settings.Schemas.Add("http://tempuri.com/CCC/assignment/v1", @"D:\my.xsd");
            settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;

            StringReader strm = new StringReader(assignmentXML);

            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(strm, settings);
            XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
            document.Load(reader);

            ValidationEventHandler eventHandler = new ValidationEventHandler(ValidationHandler);

            // call to Validate 
            document.Validate(eventHandler);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    static void ValidationHandler(object sender, ValidationEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.Severity)
        {
            case XmlSeverityType.Error:
                Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", e.Message);
                break;
            case XmlSeverityType.Warning:
                Console.WriteLine("Warning {0}", e.Message);
                break;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment.
But I am trying to achieve this in WSO2 ESB